# Re connect SonarQube with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have the next problem. We have the lastest LTS versions from Sonarqube and Jenkins. Both are connect and run without problem.

Now we want to change Sonarqube host. For example:

Before:
http://our-url:9000/sonar

Now:
http://our-url:9000

We clone the server to test if all works fine or not. Change URL from Sonarqube inside Jenkins and run a test project and everything is fine but when we wanna see the existing projects they are not linked to Sonarqube. Thats the problem.

Somebody knows how re connect that project again? Without run another test? Well, if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: if a project is not analyzed by sonarqube you will not be able to see it in sonarqube UI/database.

Comment: @prudviraj the problem is with old analyzed projects. But I can solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have this weird and unusual problem, you can solved it if you go to Jenkins folder > Jobs > Your Job > build > # of the builds (need to edit all) > Edit the text file. Then search the sonarqube URL and edit it.

Cheers!!

Comment: if you solved the problem, then please accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a webhook on sonar-side:

```
https://<your Jenkins instance>/sonarqube-webhook/
```

If you use pipeline you can find useful info at: https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/